# Azure pipeline Docker `all pipe instances are busy`

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

When running a build pipeline with `maven` and `docker-maven-plugin` sometimes(more than 50% of the time) it throws following error and pipeline fails.

```
Jun 18, 2019 1:57:12 AM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.io.FileNotFoundException) caught when processing request to {}->npipe://127.0.0.1:1: \\.\pipe\docker_engine (All pipe instances are busy)
Jun 18, 2019 1:57:12 AM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
```

I can see in the log that multiple retry attempts, but all fails. Is there any way that I can overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this problem:

I added the right version of   `docker-maven-plugin`  **1.4.10**

[dockerfile-maven-plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.spotify/dockerfile-maven-plugin)